# Angular checkbox not submitted

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have an angular form with a checkbox ready to submit.

```
<form name="productForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit='action(productForm.$valid)' novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type='checkbox' name='subtract' data-ng-model='product.subtract'/>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is The default value of this thing in database is 1.

I assume if I don't select the checkbox it will record 0 in the database for me.  But somehow this input checkbox is not submitted and the db just takes the defined default value '1'.

Any chance someone know what is happening here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you dont initialize the scope variable `product.subtract` in the controller as,

```
$scope.product = {};
$scope.product.subtract = 0; //not selected by default
```

and

```
<input type='checkbox' name='subtract' data-ng-model='product.subtract' ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
```

`ng-true-value` & `ng-false-value` represent the checkbox `true` `false` statuses based on checked.

> if you do not initialize a scope variable within the controller or using `ng-init` then there is no scope variable create until you made a change to the `ng-model`. so here, if u dont have the scope variable, and then you submit the form without ticking the checkbox then there is no scope variable called `$scope.product.subtract`.

Comment: great, glad to help u :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in addition to this. I"ve noticed that use a boolean on the checkbox can cause issues.

Convert your model into a string (or int) and change the input to be something like this will work

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='mgModel' ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'" />
```

But if you true to use a straight boolean. You'll find it'll not send the change up to parent controllers etc. So this will fail or cause wired binding issues

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='mgModel' ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" />
```

So if you're having issues with bind a true/false value. Try changing it to a string or int.